# Selected keyboard layout has to be re-selected to work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use the `English (US, Alternative international)` layout, which allows me to type some characters (`ç`, `á`, `ã`, etc.), but when I start Ubuntu and try to type any of these characters, it becomes `'c`, `~a`, etc. When I re-select the same keyboard layout, it works!

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Ubuntu version is above 12.04 you can change the default keyboard layout by editing the keyboard layout file:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/keyboard
```

and change the **XKBLAYOUT** option to **"us-intl"**

Reboot your system and test the new layout.

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: Is your Ubuntu version above 12.04?

Comment: Yes, its 15.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your keyboard layout in the terminal with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer to the question.